# What do I roll to maintain concentration while Wild Shaped?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, druid, wild-shape, concentration

I'm building a level 5 Moon Druid and chose the variant human race - so I decided to take 2 feats: War Caster and Resilient (Con). My goal here is to cast concentration spells and then Wild Shape into a brown bear to tank for my party. Now bear with me (pun intended):

If I get hit as a bear, do I make a Constitution saving throw with the bear's stats? Or would I make it using my druid's stats (he currently has a Con score of 16 con, so I'd have a Con saving throw modifier of +6)?

## Edit

I think I know why was I confused. I'm using DnD beyond, and in the creature tab, I added the brown bear. Now, I see that it has a saving throw of +6 CON, +3 IN and +6 WIS. Basically, I thought it was its base saving throws, but it represents my **character** saving throws. So Dnd Beyond actually already makes the calculation for you !

Thank you all of your answers!

Comment: In general, we prefer that [each post be limited to one overarching question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6453/33569). That said, your secondary question about whether feats apply while Wild Shaped are already covered in the following 2 questions, so I've edited that part out: [Do any feats carry over when in Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71314/33569), [Does a Wild Shaped druid with the War Caster feat have advantage on concentration checks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/149166/33569)

Comment: Also related: [What values do I recalculate when I Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136066/what-values-do-i-recalculate-when-i-wild-shape)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Use the bear's Con modifier + your proficiency bonus: +6 total

The druid's [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167) feature specifies how your new form's statistics interact with those of your regular form:

> While you are transformed, the following rules apply:
>
> - Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but
>   you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and
>   Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw
>   proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature. If the
>   creature has the same proficiency as you and the bonus in its stat
>   block is higher than yours, use the creature’s bonus instead of
>   yours.
> - [...]
> - You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or
>   other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable
>   of doing so. [...]

In this case, you're using Wild Shape to turn into a [brown bear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/brown-bear). The brown bear has a Constitution score of 16 (a +3 modifier), and is not proficient in any saving throws. Your regular human form also has a Constitution score of 16 (a +3 modifier) - but your Resilient feat gives you proficiency in Constitution saving throws. Since you're level 5, your proficiency bonus is also +3, for a total modifier of +6.

Even if you didn't retain the benefit of features from your race/class (in this case, your feats), the Wild Shape feature explicitly says you retain your own saving throw proficiencies.

---

Now, the question of what your total Constitution saving throw modifier then becomes might seem a little confusing at first, because you may wonder whether your proficiency bonus is retained or not. However, this is clarified in an episode of Dragon Talk and a few unofficial tweets by rules designer Jeremy Crawford (cited in [this answer by Bash to a related question about what values are recalculated in Wild Shape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147683/33569)).

First, [Crawford clarified the intent of the first bullet point of Wild Shape in this series of tweets in 2015](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/558355703530672128):

> *Debate resolution. Druid in wildshape. Keep prof bonus to attack or use beast's stats unmodified?*
>
> **A druid in beast form uses his or her proficiencies, except when the beast has the same proficiency with a higher bonus.**
>
> *That doesn't answer the Q. Druid is not prof in claw/bite. Black bear form, +3 for bear, or prof+2 for druid w/ bear str?*
>
> **The intent is that the druid uses the bonus in the beast's stat block for any proficiency the druid lacks.**

Second, Crawford stated the following in the [Sage Advice segment of the April 6, 2017 episode of Dragon Talk](http://edit.dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/chris-avellone-and-philip-daigle-planescape-torment-enhanced-edition), in response to a question about what happens if you Wild Shape into a creature with a lower modifier to a skill like Stealth:

> You get to use your proficiency bonus. But you do use the creature's Dexterity modifier. This is where it gets tricky. Use your proficiency bonus for anything where you're both proficient, but only if yours is higher - but you use the physical stats of the beast.

The same logic applies to saving throws.

Finally, [Crawford reiterated the meaning of the first bullet point of Wild Shape in this 2018 tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/960225632578764800):

> *I have seen two different tweets of yours, so I am looking for clarity. My lvl 5 druid has a +3 prof bonus, when I shape into a brown bear I have a str of 19 and an attack bonus of 5. Do I add my druid prof bonus to attack bringing it to +7? Thank you!*
>
> **The Wild Shape feature does not let you add your proficiency bonus to the proficiency bonus of your beast form. The first bullet of the class feature details which proficiency bonus you use (PH, 67).**

In summary:

- If the beast's proficient in a physical saving throw (Str/Dex/Con)
  and its modifier to the saving throw is higher than yours, just use
  the beast's saving throw modifier (whether or not you're proficient).
- If the beast's not proficient and neither are you, use the beast's
  saving throw modifier. Simple.
- **If the beast's not proficient but you are, *then* you add your
  proficiency bonus to the beast's corresponding ability modifier.**

In this case, the last scenario is applicable. You're proficient in saving throws, but the brown bear is not. Thus, you add your proficiency bonus of +3 to the brown bear's Constitution modifier of +3, for a total of +6.

(And as detailed in [this linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71314/33569), you do retain the benefit of your War Caster feat, so you have advantage on your Constitution saving throws to maintain concentration - even in Wild Shape.)

Comment: +1, this answer doesn't confuse 'con modifier' with 'profiency modifier'.

Comment: I think your summary may need some clarification ; as written, it doesn't say what happens if the beast has proficiency but a lower total bonus (which should probably be kept for other questions/answers), and it may even encourage the use of beast stats for int/wis/cha saving throws.
As most (if not all?) beasts don't have any saving throw proficiency, I think it may be better to stick to the "pick the appropriate ability modifier, add your own proficiency bonus if you have proficiency" part - which should'nt bring the usual Wild Shape confusion.

Comment: Crawford's tweets are as confusing and ambiguous as the rules, honestly, and this answer doesn't really clarify the issue. I think the bottom line is that the Druid doesn't lose anything except, _potentially_, the score modifiers of CON, DEX and STR. Your stats are _replaced_ by those of the beast so, even if your DEX is higher than that of the beast's, you use the beast's DEX. Granted they have it, Druids can always use their saving throw proficiency bonus but, if the beast happens to have a higher one, the character can use that instead.

Comment: [DnD Beyond analysis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/154190/51400) shows that if the beast has proficiency, but you don't, you can't use the value displayed in it's stat block, and must apply your own proficiency bonus on top of the (updated, if physical) ability modifier.

Answer (score 6):

## You use the bear's Constitution

According to the official rules in D&D-5e regarding [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167):

> Your game statistics are **replaced** by the statistics **of the beast**, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores.

The developers were kind enough to specify which parts of your character you retain, and as you just read, Constitution is not one of those.

Furthermore...

> Transforming doesn't break your concentration on a spell you've already cast, however, or prevent you from taking actions that are part of a spell.

If your concentration breaks and the spell ends, you cannot cast it again until you transform back to your initial form. The saving throw is made using the beast's (*Bear's*) Constitution saving throw modifier + any saving throw proficiency bonus you may have, or the beast's if it's higher than yours, as explained below.

> You also **retain all** of your **skill** and **saving throw proficiencies**, in addition to gaining those of the creature. If the creature has the same proficiency as you and the bonus in its stat block is higher than yours, use the creature's bonus instead of yours.

---

You asked:

> If I get hit as a bear, do I make a Constitution saving throw with the bear's stats? Or would I make it using my druid's stats

Unless the bear's ability modifier or saving throw proficiency is higher you use the Druid's.

For example, if you have a Constitution Modifier +1 and the Bear's is +2 you would use the bear. Same applies to proficiency bonuses on saving throws.

The Brown Bear has a Constitution Modifier of +3, without proficiency in saving throws. Your human form Constitution Modifier is a +3 which means use yours. Your Resilient feat, though, gives you proficiency in Constitution saving throws and since you are level 5, your proficiency bonus is a +3.

Comment: As far as I understand, RAW, you _can_ use the beast's bonus for that saving throw instead of yours, **if** you **and** the beast _share_ proficiency in that saving throw. In all other cases, you must use **your** saving throw bonus.

Comment: @StackLLoyd According to Roll20 "If the creature has the same proficiency as you and the bonus in its stat block is higher than yours, use the creature's bonus instead of yours." It doesn't say "you can use the creature's bonus instead" it simply says you use it. I could have misinterpreted though.

Comment: I'm sorry, my point wasn't about whether you _can_ or _must_ use the creature's bonus, but rather _when_ it's allowed to use it. Though honestly confusing, it seems that, RAW, **both** you and the creature must have proficiency in that saving throw for you to use the creature's bonus. Otherwise, you use your bonus.

Comment: "You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature". That means that if you do not have proficiency but the beast does you "gain" it. Unless you're talking about something else.

Comment: This answer seems wrong. "Your human form Constitution Modifier is a +3 which means you choose the Beast's" is erroneous, you would also use the bears if your own constitution modifier is +0 or +5, because you use the bear's constitution for everything. You get to use the beast's proficiency if it is higher (expertise), you do not get to use your own con score for saves if it happens to be higher than the beasts. The simple terms equation is not correct.

Comment: I said you choose the Beast's because it is a +3  and your initial form's con is +3 which means that there is no difference whatsoever. I also clearly stated in my answer that if the initial form's modifier is lower or higher he will use the beast's so I guess what confused you is the phrasing. Regarding the proficiency bonus if yours is lower than the beast's then you use the beast's if not then you use yours.

Comment: "if Beast's Con Modifier >= Druid's Con Modifier use Beast's else use Druid's (Same applies to proficiencies in saving throws)." -> This is wrong, you never get to use your own con modifier. It doesn't matter if you have a con modifer of 0 or 200, you're stuck using the bear's con modifier if you are in bear form. Only the proficiency bonus uses whichever is higher.

Comment: Again, my mistake I meant saving throw prof only. Updated the question.

Comment: First part is nice.
Second part is at best confusing :
"Unless the bear's ability modifier or saving throw proficiency is higher you use the Druid's." => I don't know if you mean the druid's ability score, proficiency bonus, or total.
"if Beast's Con Save Prof Modifier >= Druid's Con Save Prof Modifier use Beast's else use Druid's" => what is a "save prof modifier"? You mean proficiency bonus ? Total ?