# How does the druid's Wild Shape feature interact with magic tomes and manuals that increase a character's ability scores?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, wild-shape

Certain tomes and manuals increase the ability score of a character that uses them. As these tomes/manuals are, I suppose, 'consumed', can a druid who just entered Wild Shape benefit from such a tome/manual (i.e. Dex, Con, Str)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking if the increased ability score is still available when Wild Shaped?

Comment: @Steve Wild Shape has its own Dex, Con, Str, so I guess the question is which stats will be increased.

Comment: Related: "[Does Durable improve the Con of a Wild Shape form?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71348)" and "[Do ability score improvements apply to a druid's wild shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108274)"

Comment: Also confused- is the question "Does a Druid retain the ability score increase while in wildshape" or "While in Wild Shape, can a druid use a tome to gain an ability score increase to their beast form?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### They do not affect Str, Dex, Con

When an ability score is permanently increased such as from a tome or ASI that is the Druid’s ability score. Str, Dex and Con are replaced during wild shape so the Druid’s ability score is irrelevant.

Where the increase is from an “always on” item like an Ioun Stone, the wild shape can benefit from that.

Comment: Can you cite anything to support your answer here?