# Is the 'Tough' feat's additional health still added when Wild Shaped/Shapeshifted?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, druid, wild-shape, hit-points

Following on from this question: [Do any feats carry over when in Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71314/do-any-feats-carry-over-when-in-wild-shape)

It seems all feats carry over to your new form if your new form is capable of using them (so Mounted Combatant and Inspiring leader would usually be ruled as unusable in most circumstances). But what about Tough?

> Your hit point maximum increases by an amount equal to twice your
>   level when you gain this feat. Whenever you gain a level thereafter,
>   your hit point maximum increases by an additional 2 hit points.

Would this increase your maximum HP by the same amount when in the form of a rat, or brown bear?

Comment: Albert Masclans' and adclark09's answers outline the two possible interpretations of the rules, and I don't know which is correct. The order of operations and whether current or base HP is overridden are the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd say this question is pretty much answered in the very same question you provided.

Even though you retain all the benefits from the feats you have, the **game statistics are changed, and that includes HP**.

That means that you will not retain the extra HP from Tough for the duration of the Wild Shape since **beast's HP override yours**.

---

As clarified in a comment by [Miniman](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/15469/miniman):

*Tough changes your HP maximum when you level rather than all the time.*

Comment: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/642088434673152000?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw

Comment: now addressed (and agreeing) in [Sage Advice, July 2016](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-july-2016)