# Does the Tough feat's hit point bonus apply to a Druid's wild shapes?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, druid, wild-shape, hit-dice

A Druid in Wild Shape takes on all the wild shape creature's physical ability scores, and those creatures have a number of listed Hit Dice, so does the Druid get to add the additional 2 hp per hit dice from the Tough feat to their wild shape forms?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why would the Tough feat impact hit dice at all? Or rather, what particular parts of these features are confusing you?

Comment: @Medix2 Duplicate of [Is the 'Tough' feat's additional health still added when Wild Shaped/Shapeshifted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73838/14878) then