# When a Yuan-Ti or Slaad shapechanges, do they retain their class abilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The MM on page 277 states:

> It's statistics, other than its size, are the same in each form.

Does that mean that their abilities (spellcasting, resistances, etc.) retain as well or just the statistics, but otherwise have the abilities and attacks of their polymorphed form (Medium Snake for Yuan-Ti Malison and whatever I choose for the Slaad)?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/71315/23970), while not crafted for your situation, has your answer in it.

Comment: Thanks, @nitsua60. That's what I thought they meant by "Statistics" but wasn't sure. This is my first time DMing and didn't want to assume that they could still cast in their shapechange form, but seems like they can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes; they retain absolutely everything else contained in the stat block excluding the exception mentioned. In this case, size is the only thing that changes.

The easy way to tackle this in the future, is if you take a look at a Monster Stat block in the "Monster Manual" you'll see that it has been designed over a piece of parchment. One piece of parchment encompasses all of the statistics for a single monster. Meaning if there is ever an exception, it is the only thing on that entire piece of parchment that changes.