# Is a druid in wild shape actually a beast?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, animals

Is a druid in wild shape actually a beast?

e.g. would the Speak with Animals work to communicate with the druid?

> You gain the ability to comprehend and verbally communicate with beasts for the duration.

Answer (score 23):

## Yes, a druid in Wild Shape is a beast

For the purposes of creature type you are a 'Beast' (or Elemental at L10) while in Wild Shape form and no longer Humanoid. As it has been pointed out to me by a fellow exchange friend, you are still yourself. Still a druid (with your memories and personality in tact). You never stop being who you are, but your form alters in such a all encompassing way that you do, indeed, stop being a humanoid.

> "...Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature..."

So this is, before anything else, saying everything you are is replaced by that of your new form; including creature type. It then gives you exceptions as to what is NOT altered and thus retained from your Druid form, an exception to the Wild Shape rule.

This does have implications such as 'Speak with Animals' making you a legal target as well as (perhaps the most interesting) anything that must target a humanoid (Such as Hold Person and Charm Person) can no longer target you. Since you are now only a Beast.

Comment: What about languages? Are they supressed for the duration of the Wild Shape?

Comment: @Punkgeon You retain ALL features from class, race, and other choices. This includes Languages. You can **understand** any proficient languages but are an animal and incapable of **speaking** those languages as per *"...and may use those features if your form is physically able to..."*