# Would a Ranger’s Favored-Enemy feature apply to a Druid using Wildshape?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, wild-shape, ranger

If a Ranger has dragons and humanoids chosen as their favored enemies, would they be able to benefit from this feature if tracking a druid (humanoid) while in Wild Shape (beast)?

Comment: Related: [Is a druid in wild shape actually a beast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79540/33707)

Comment: Are you talking about the PHB ranger or the UA revised ranger? The revised ranger can choose humanoids (in general) as one of their favored enemies, but PHB rangers can only choose two races of humanoid as their favored enemy (not humanoids in general): https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#FavoredEnemy

Answer (score 9):

## No, not while they are shaped out of the favored enemy type

While in wild shape the Druid is considered a beast in all respects that are laid out in the rules for Wild Shape.

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast [..]

This means that while wild shaped, the Druid is no longer a humanoid but is the type of the beast. So, the ranger would no longer get advantage on checks to track the Druid while in that form.

Comment: Huh, never realized the creature type transfers.  Does that mean you could cast Animal Messenger on a druid wildshaped as a tiny creature?

Comment: @PinkSweetener: Technically I see no reason why not, though it would be a very strange way to use it.

Comment: re:animal messenger - Could be a rather tricky way to RAW get rid of an enemy druid for 24 hours. Or to deliver them to the authorities. (Most DMs would put a stop to this somehow, but it's a really cute idea).

Comment: @pink sweetner, that deserves its own question

Comment: Tricksy, sneaky druids and their wildshaping! :)