# Can a Horncaller control a Druid who is using Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, druid, wild-shape

In Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica there is an enemy, [Horncaller](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/horncaller), who has an interesting ability:

> **One with the Worldsoul.** The horncaller chooses one beast it can see within 30 feet of it. If the beast can hear the horncaller, the beast uses its reaction to make one melee attack against a target that the horncaller can see.
>
> —**Horncaller**, Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica, pg. 253

According to the question linked at the bottom, it seems that a Druid using Wild Shape is in fact a Beast during that time. Can the horncaller force the Druid to use its reaction to attack an ally?

(Link for reference: [Is a druid in wild shape actually a beast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79540/is-a-druid-in-wild-shape-actually-a-beast) )

Comment: Somewhat related on [How does wild shape interact with dominate beast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96836/how-does-wild-shape-interact-with-dominate-beast)

Comment: Related indeed, though now we can't trust the sage advice column anymore. (Because of whatever that was - I don't really remember.)

Comment: Mainly because three years worth of modules (since that post) might have cleared up whether the Druid Beasts can be targeted by "beast" spells. It is very possible that, although they are "beasts" there is a module/official book that says they cannot be targeted by "beast" targeting spells/abilities.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## This would work on a wild shaped druid

Wild Shape says:

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores.

Creature type is part of a creature's statistics and thus the druid literally becomes a beast in wild shape form. And, because they are a beast, they are treated no different than "normal" beasts in any way.

Thus, the Horncaller ability would unambiguously affect a wild shaped druid since it targets "one beast it can see within 30 feet of it". And, as the ability does not make any specific restrictions, the druid can be forced to make an attack on an ally using it.