# Can an intellect devourer be charmed by charm person?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, charmed

The intellect devourer is a *Tiny aberration*, which would normally make it immune to the 1st level spell [*charm person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person), but when it successfully uses its ***Body Thief*** ability on a *Medium humanoid*:

> The intellect devourer
>   retains its Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores, as
>   well as its understanding of Deep Speech, its telepathy, and
>   its traits. It otherwise adopts the target's statistics.

Does adopting the target's statistics include the monster type changing from an aberration into a humanoid, which makes it vulnerable to *charm person*?

What happens when a charmed intellect devourer is Charisma (Persuasion) check'd into teleporting out of its host's skull and it becomes a *Tiny aberration* again? Is it still charmed?

Comment: Related: "[What all is included in a creature's game statistics?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138783)"

Comment: The answer to the second question linked by @Medix2 reminds us that an intellect devourer inhabiting a humanoid can't be targeted by charm person in the first place. Does that mean this question deals with an impossible situation?

Answer (score 3):

Per [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138783/what-all-is-included-in-a-creatures-game-statistics), a creature's game statistics includes its type. One useful parallel is the the Druid's ***Wild Shape*** ability, which we have seen 
[really does turn the Druid into a beast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79540/is-a-druid-in-wild-shape-actually-a-beast); for the same reasons, the intellect devourer that uses ***Body Thief*** really does turn into a humanoid.

It has also been established that, when something under the effect of a spell becomes an invalid target, [the affected entity is no longer affected](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133379/is-a-spell-suppressed-or-removed-when-the-target-temporarily-becomes-invalid?noredirect=1) (unless/until it becomes a valid target again). So the intellect devourer would stop being charmed by *charm person* when it resumed its true form.