# Does a Goliath's carry weight bonus work in wildshape?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

I had a silly idea for a group of gnomes to team up with a Goliath who shifts into a bear to serve as a battle platform for them to ride and attack with lances/shoot bows/cast from. Maybe mount a ballista or heavy crossbow on his back. You know, silly ideas.

But before I present this idea to my group/DM, I'm curious exactly how far this bends the rules: If a Goliath Druid wildshapes into a brown bear, does his racial Powerful Build trait carry over when he's shifted, so he'd count as a Huge creature for carry weight?

Comment: closely related, possible duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71314/23970

Comment: You shapeshift into the bear equivalent of a bodybuilder

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, the Powerful Build ability will work while Wild Shaped. Wild Shape allows you to use your racial features:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if your new form is physically capable of doing so.

And, just for completeness, Powerful Build:

> You count as one size larger when determining your carrying capacity and the weight you can push, drag, or lift.

There's nothing there that would prevent it from working while Wild Shaped, so yep, you'd count as Huge when Wild Shaped into a Large creature.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes, exactly!

Part of **Wild Shape** is the following term:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class,
> **race**, or other source and can use them if the new
> form is physically capable of doing so. [...]

So the carrying capacity would be calculated with the bears strength and size plus it counts as one size category larger for this.