# What happens when you have resistance and Wild Shape into a beast with vulnerability?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, damage-resistance, vulnerability

So a lot of stuff is written about Wild Shape in the rules and here on this page. One question I have not found asked and especially not found answered yet is:
What happens when I have resistance to for example fire damage by racial or class feature and Wild Shape into a beast with vulnerability against the same type.

I could imagine 4 ways:

- vulnerability is not received by Wild Shape
- vulnerability and resistance cancel each others out
- vulnerability always beats resistance
- resistance always beats vulnerability

I could imagine 2nd as general rule and first in the case of a wild shaped totem warrior barbarian. But I am not sure at all.

My case would be a totem warrior barbarian druid multiclass. The Wild Shape is homebrew but the most common case without homebrew would be an earth elemental which is vulnerable to Thunder Damage.

Comment: The way resistance and vulnerability interact when you have both is definitely covered by the question Erik linked above. If you have a question about a particular feature granting resistance interacting with wild shape, I would edit the question to ask specifically about that interaction.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I mean. The question already implies its about wildshape. Because its not stated how it would interact. But i guess it will act as in the linked question yeah

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, such as wildshape including some aspect that isn't just a way to stack the two, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: If your question is just about resistance and vulnerability, then it’s a duplicate. *But* if your questions is about how a certain feature interacts with Wild Shape, it might not be a dupe.

Comment: I guess we can handle it as a dupe. Even if not clearly specified in Wild Shape this is the way of handling it that makes most sense. Thank you guys.

Comment: Not sure whether it's worth adding as a dupe link, but at least related: [Does a wildshaped druid retain his/her racial resistances?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138169)