# Does Circle of the Forged increase the Wildshape AC by 2 or 3?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, eberron, warforged

The druid's Wild Shape feature in D&D 5e says:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so. However, you can't use any of your special senses, such as darkvision, unless your new form also has that sense.

From the warforged's Integrated Protection racial trait:

> You gain a +1 bonus to Armor Class

From *[Exploring Eberron](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/315887/Exploring-Eberron)*'s Circle of the Forged Skin of Steel feature:

> Starting at 2nd level, while you are transformed by Wild Shape,
> you gain the following benefits: You gain a +2 bonus to Armor Class...

Warforged druids [may not normally keep Integrated Protection when wildshaped](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164777/what-is-the-ac-of-a-warforged-druid-when-wild-shaped) because the shape they transform into isn't built like a warforged, but Circle of the Forged clearly lets them keep their wood and metal composition:

> While in beast form, your body is made from the same materials as a warforged; your muscles are rootlike tendrils protected by armored plates. It’s obvious to an observer that you are not a normal animal.

So does that mean if you're a Circle of the Forged warforged druid, you get a +3 AC bonus to whatever beast's natural armor you turn into? E.g. Giant spider = 14 + 1 + 2 = 17?

This seems like a big difference from normal druids, even moon druids, so I wanted to double check.

Comment: Is Exploring Eberron a third party supplement?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov it is, though written by the official Eberron creator and his team.

Comment: I think this is a dupe, as your question really comes down to whether or not Integrated Protection applies while wildshaped, which the linked question addresses.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. What Jeremy Crawford said about "A racial trait works with Wild Shape unless that trait requires **anatomy the beast form lacks**." is invalid because at the time, wildshape's form is still flesh and blood, whereas Circle of the Forge specifically says wood and metal

Comment: It would be helpful to include any relevant text from Exploring Eberron, otherwise you might be waiting for someone who has the book to see this and give an answer.

Comment: @stashinko Hi there - can you make your question title specific please - it makes it easier to find answers, e.g.: Does Circle of the Forged increase the AC of a druid in Wildhshape? Something on those lines. :)

Answer (score 5):

### By RAW, You would get the full +3 AC. This is probably not intended.

The druids [*Wild Shape*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#ClassFeatures) states:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so.

The warforged [*Integrated Protection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/eberron-rising-from-the-last-war) says:

> **Integrated Protection.** Your body has built-in defensive layers, which can be enhanced with armor.
>
> - You gain a +1 bonus to Armor Class.
> - [...]

For the other druid subclasses this would not work [as answered here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164777/what-is-the-ac-of-a-warforged-druid-when-wild-shaped?noredirect=1&lq=1), but this subclass specifies "*your body is made from the same materials as a warforged*", and so the +1 AC would carry over to the Wild Shape. However, this may not be the intention of the feature, as having +3 AC can be pretty dramatically game changing. As well, the other parts of the *Circle of the Forged* match features from the Warforged’s stats:

> [...]
>
> - You have advantage on saving throws against being poisoned, and you have resistance to poison damage.
> - You don’t need to eat, drink, or breathe.
> - You are immune to disease.
> - You don’t need to sleep, and magic can’t put you to sleep.

This seems to be written as if the other racial features would not carry over into the *Wild Shape* form, and as such I think it is safe to assume they are not intended to stack.

Comment: I somewhat agree that it may not be intended. To me it sounds like the warforged racial traits were repeated to allow for other races (see Bladesong racial restrictions being lifted).

Answer (score 2):

### You get +2 AC

The Druid Wildshape feature [states](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#ClassFeatures):

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them **if the new form is physically capable of doing so**. However, you can’t use any of your special senses, such as darkvision, unless your new form also has that sense.

While the Warforged Integrated Protection grants:

> **Your body has built-in defensive layers**, which can be enhanced with armor:
>
> - You gain a +1 bonus to Armor Class.

**Being made of metal does not mean you have integrated protection**
The Integrated Protection feature is clear that it is a quality of that particular body. It doesn't matter whether a new body is also made of metal, it is still not constructed in the same way as the Warforged's original body. A wildshaped metal/wood wolf would not have the "built-in defensive layers" that grant Integrated Protection. This is different from other features that rely on skill such as a Goblin's Nimble Escape, or on magic such as an Aasimar's healing hands.