# Druid Wild Shape and physical stats

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

I am trying a multi-class character I haven't tried before, a Barbarian Druid. Since my strength is gonna be pretty high from being a barbarian, I was wandering, if my physical stats are higher than the stats of the creature I'm changing into, can i use my character's stats, or is it a 'no matter what you use the creature's stat's ' kind of thing?
P.S. I don't have a whole lot of D&D experience, so the more detail, the better. Thanks :)

Comment: related: [feats in wild shape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71314/23970) (discusses "statistics" generally)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### No.

When a druid assumes a form, he takes on all the statistics block of an average member of that species. Your barbarian/druid physical abilities only work in the original form.

From the [SRD](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Classes:Druid#toc_6):

> - Your game Statistics are replaced by the Statistics of the beast, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature. If the creature has the same proficiency as you and the bonus in its stat block is higher than yours, use the creature's bonus instead of yours. If the creature has any legendary or lair actions, you can't use them.
> - When you transform, you assume the beast's Hit Points and Hit Dice. When you revert to your normal form, you return to the number of hit points you had before you transformed. However, if you revert as a result of Dropping to 0 Hit Points, any excess damage carries over to your normal form.

Answer (score 7):

**You may use only the Beast's physical stats.**

This isn't from the SRD, but wild shape rules are quite explicit about this:

> While you are transformed, the following rules apply:
>   Your game statistics are **replaced by the statistics of the beast**, but *you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores.*

Comment: @royalmurder--the link you included was flagged for removal as it's to a copyright-infringing site. (Only circle of the land is in the SRD, for instance.) I'd also note that the second part of your answer kinds reads like "link-only." It'd be better, after finding a legit source, to describe a bit of what you're linking (a) so that the reader knows whether to follow or not, and (b) so your answer's less susceptible to link-rot. I've deleted the line for now; feel free to edit again to put in a more robust discussion of what a player new to druids should consider.