# When transformed by the Shapechange spell, do you retain the benefits of your feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

Some friends and I are playing a level-20 battle royale, so rules are very important.

I was wondering if the creature's new form retains their feats when using the *shapechange* spell (specifically Polearm Master and War Caster).

Comment: Related: [Do any feats carry over when in Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/71315/48759)

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, feats transfer to *shapechange*d forms

The [*shapechange*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange) spell description says:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them, provided that your new form is physically capable of doing so. You can't use any special senses you have (for example, darkvision) unless your new form also has that sense.

This includes all feats, though to utilise them your new form must be physically capable of doing so (i.e. you must be able to wield a glaive, halberd, etc. for Polearm Master, and must have a spellcasting ability to use War Caster).

For a full explanation, see: [Do any feats carry over when in Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71314/do-any-feats-carry-over-when-in-wild-shape)

Comment: Note that the new shape would have a spellcasting ability assuming the old form did (which they must have given the fact they have the War Caster feat and it is a prereq). Since Class features carry over, spellcasting would as well.