# Can you use Shapechange with character feats to Grapple the Tarrasque?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, combat

After I had read the *Monster Manual*'s [Tarrasque](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tarrasque) entry, I began thinking of ways to kill it. The first thing that came to mind is for 1 party member to become a creature that is Huge in size, then grapple the Tarrasque while other members of the party attacked it.

My idea is to have a Level 20 Variant Human with at least 13 STR and 20 INT with the [War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster) and [Grappler](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/grappler) feats. Before the battle, they would use the 9th level spell [Shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange) to turn into a Storm Giant. As the battle begins, he would attempt to grapple the Tarrasque. It wouldn't be guaranteed, but it would still be possible because the storm giant overall has a +4 over the Tarrasque's Athletics, and has advantage. This makes the probability of the character winning to (check my math) around 80%.

Once the Tarrasque is grappled, the Storm Giant would use subsequent turns to re-grapple if it escapes, or to use their action to make it restrained. While this is happening, other party members would be supporting the giant or nuking the Tarrasque with magical bows. And every time the giant was hit, he would get advantage and +10 to the concentration saving throw.

My optimal party composition would be 1 or 2 Life Clerics or similar healers who are constantly healing the Storm Giant, 3 fighters with magical bows, and 1 Wizard or Sorcerer who are buffing the Storm Giant and the rest of the fighting force.

**When you use the Shapechange spell, do you keep all of the character's feats? And is the Tarrasque being grappled affected by his Legendary Resistance?**

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe of your first question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139009/52137 (if you agree this Q&A answers that, you may wish to edit out of this one and focus on the other one)

Comment: As Someone_Evil said, the first part of your bolded question is already addressed by your other question. Also, it seems like most of your question is presenting your reasoning for asking, but the reasoning seems largely unnecessary for the question. It might make more sense instead to directly ask (while including the context) whether your plan as a whole will work as written; then people could point out any possible flaws in the plan.

Answer (score 12):

## Yes, you can grapple the tarrasque

As discussed in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139009/when-transformed-by-the-shapechange-spell-do-you-retain-the-benefits-of-your-fe), you keep the benefit of your feats when you shapechange.  And you're correct that Legendary Resistance won't let the tarrasque avoid a grapple.

## But that won't stop it from attacking you

Even if you pin the tarrasque with your grappler feat, all that does is give it disadvantage on its attacks against you.  Its attacks are at +19 to hit, and a storm giant's AC is 16, so the disadvantage won't help you very much.

The tarrasque does an average of 212 damage per round (its attacks average 36, 28, 28, 32, 24 damage; it also gets legendary actions which can be two more attacks for 28 and 36 damage).

## And that's okay

It appears that the tarrasque's attacks are nonmagical (!), so a *stoneskin* spell will halve the incoming damage.  Your concentration checks seem surprisingly safe: the storm giant gets +10 to his constitution save, and with the *stoneskin* spell you're unlikely to need more than a DC10 save.

Two high-level clerics can heal you through the damage for several rounds (*heal* restores 10hp per level of the spell slot).

But the main thing you're getting from this grappling thing is you're forcing the tarrasque to attack you (with your *stoneskin* spell, and with your size making you too large to swallow) rather than attack one of your more fragile allies.  And you're giving your allies advantage on their attack rolls, once the tarrasque is restrained.

That seems worthwhile.

Comment: Pinning a creature with the Grappler feat imposes the restrained condition (on you and the pinned creature) which includes giving all attack rolls against the creature advantage meaning all allies gets advantage as well. Also, what is forcing the tarrasque to attack 'you'? Are you assuming all allies are outside the terrasque's reach (10 to 20 ft.)?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming all allies are outside the tarrasque's reach.  OP writes that most of his allies will have bows; others will be healers, and the *heal* spell has range 60 ft.

Comment: May be best to clarify that you would have to get *stoneskin* from someone else as both *shapechange* and *stoneskin* require concentration.

Comment: Nice analysis. The answer part of your response is fairly short. Consider adding a portion about saves vs checks to escape grapples to support your answer, as this seems to be the concept the question wanted to verify.