# Does a druid in wild shape still benefit from the speed increase of the Mobile feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, movement, druid, wild-shape

Since in [wild shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#WildShape) "You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so" and the [Mobile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mobile) feat just says "Your speed increases by 10 feet", do a Druid's wild shapes benefit from the speed increase from Mobile?

Comment: Related on [Wildshape and alert/lucky feats](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71314/do-the-alert-and-lucky-feats-carry-over-when-in-wild-shape). Possible duplicate, not sure we need a question for every feat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the Alert and Lucky feats carry over when in Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71314/do-the-alert-and-lucky-feats-carry-over-when-in-wild-shape)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### You generally continue to benefit from Mobile in wild shape

The description of the [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#WildShape) feature states, in part:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them **if the new form is physically capable of doing so**.

Taking feats is a feature of your class giving you ability score increases, so it will be retained by any creature that is physically capable of movement. Mobile does not care about the mode of movement, whether you are walking, slithering, flying, swimming, or burrowing.

The only exception would be a creature that has no movement because it is not physically capable of moving, like a [Shrieker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17013-shrieker), or an aquatic creature on land that has no walking speed. Because you only retain the feature if the form is physically able to use it, in that case, you would not get the extra speed.

Comment: You should generally avoid answering duplicate questions in favor of flagging them as duplicate.

Comment: @Kryomaani That question is about Lucky and Alert , not Mobile. I agree that the answer argues the same,  but is very long so [its not obvious](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/if-an-answer-to-question-a-can-be-found-in-question-b-should-we-close-a-as-dupl). The second one is better , but also does not explore how it applies to speed. I think it is arguable if this is a dupe. I did search for dupes before answering, but there are so many about wild shape & feat and several I looked at did not appear to be a really good fit, either. Often, the details differ.